# change the style with ng-checked value

Tags: angularjs

I want to change a style with checkbox's enable/disable.

- For checked box -> visiblity:visible
- For Unchecked Box -> Visibility : hidden

How do I do this with angular? I tried with ng-checked but no any lucky.

```
ng-change="style={'visibility':'visible'}" ng-style="style"
```

This worked only for enabling the checkbox. After it doesn't hide when unchecked. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use ng-class and enable a class that hides your element when a condition is true or false.

html

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="visible"/> show / hide

<p ng-class="{'hideItem': !visible}"> this hides when you uncheck </p>
```

css

```
.hideItem {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

[see plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zRL5kochjFbcNgMbByBI?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use `ng-change` at all. Use `ng-model` instead

I would write something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="myModel"></input> 
<pre ng-style="{'display': (myModel) ? 'block' : 'none'}">Some text show/hide</pre>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/2179/)**</kbd>

---

> This worked only for enabling the checkbox. After it doesn't hide when unchecked.

The reason should be because of checkbox ng-model structure. To let `ng-change` to work, the model should be defined as Object (for example):

```
$scope.theModel = {value:true}
```